# TFS Xamarin.Android Build: Unable to Explicitly Set JDK to Use for the Build

Tags: xamarin, tfs, xamarin.android, tfsbuild

I have a TFS2017 build definition that contains a Xamarin.Android Build task.  The Build task has a section for "JDK Options".  JDK Options provide the following:

1. Select JDK by Version (6, 7, or 8 -- the server selects the latest installed build of the selected version)
2. Select JDK by typing in a path to the desired JDK

I have the following installed on my server:

- jdk1.7.0_55
- jdk1.8.0_92
- jdk1.8.0_131

If I use the first method and select "Version 8" it will build using jdk1.8.0_131.  If I use the first method and select "Version 7" it will build using jdk1.7.0_55.  But if I try using the 2nd method and typing in a path to jdk1.8.0_92 it always builds using the JDK that was previously selected using the first method.

Here are some paths I've tried typing in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\javac.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\javac.exe"
```

Any thoughts on why it will not accept an explicit path to the JDK?

[Here is a linky](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/xamarin-android) to the Xamarin.Android Build Task doc.

***SOLUTION (A Hacky-Sort-of solution):***

Add the path to desired JDK to 'MSBuild Additional Arguments':

```
/p:JavaSdkDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92"
```

Under 'JDK Options' select "JDK Version" and set the version to "default".  That appears to force the Build to use the desired JDK version.

Comment: False alarm.  Kinda fixed.  See above.  I still don't know why it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Is there any chance you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable setup on this machine? Is there any reason you're using a 32-bit JDK instead of 64-bit? Is your JDK Architecture set to x86 or x64?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Trevor.  Unfortunately I've checked all that.  I'm using x86 because I'm creating automated builds for this.  Up to now, we've been manually building these apps.  I'm trying to mimic the manual process as much as possible just to get the builds to succeed.  Manually building used x86.